# Can DynamoDB updates trigger a Lambda function in another region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a lambda function "mylambda" in region A and my dynamodb tables are in region B. Now I want to create dynamodb trigger in "mylambda" function. I cannot see any dynamodb tables in my lambda console as they both are in different regions. How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB Streams is region-based. Therefore, it is not possible for DynamoDB Streams to trigger a cross-region Lambda function.

However, there are alternatives:

1. `DynamoDB Table A` in `Region A` with a configured DynamoDB stream that triggers `Lambda A`. Then `Lambda A` can perform cross-region client API Calls (e.g. using `boto3` in python) to either `SQS`, `SNS`, `EventBridge` or even directly to your `Lambda B` in `Region B`.
2. Using a DynamoDB [Global Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GlobalTables.html) with Cross Region Replication.